# How to best avoid wildcards for java beans

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, wildcard

I have the following provider for usage in my service:

```
public interface DataProvider {
   public String safeDump();
}

public interface FieldDataProvider<V> extends DataProvider {

   public <T> T getField(int field, Class<T> type);

   public void setRawField(int field, V value);
}
```

With the service looking as follows

```
public interface Service<T extends DataProvider>{

    public void handleData(T dataProvider);
}
```

how do I get rid of the wildcard to inject a java bean implementing this service?

```
// to inject
public class ServiceBean implements Service<FieldDataProvider<?>>{

    public void handleData(FieldDataProvider<?> fieldDataProvider){
        String header = fieldDataProvider.getField(1, String.class)
    }
}
```

I tried just leaving out the wildCard, but `getField` suddenly returns an Object instead, which confuses me as it's the 'V' type I leave out, the 'T' type should be self-contained.

I could cast `Service<FieldDataProvider>` to `Service<FieldDataProvider<?>>` in all beans as well, but I'm not sure if this could fail or have unexpected results depending on the input.

Is there a good/better way to get rid of the wildcard and be able to inject beans like `ServiceBean`?

Comment: What is `Provider` in `Service<T extends Provider>`? Where does `T` come from in `public T getField(int field, Class<T> type);`?

Comment: @JacobG. good catch! Edited: changed `Provider` to `DataProvider`. it's the base interface for DataFieldProvider.
T is a type contained within that the method (defining the return type as the type equal to the Class of the second parameter)

Comment: Could you post the `DataProvider` interface as well?

Comment: @JacobG. Done, though it should not be closely related to the overall structure.

Comment: Thanks, I was just curious if you were using a raw type for `DataProivider`, but that isn't possible now that you've posted it. Which version of Java are you using? Using Java 13, I can't get the `getField` method to return an `Object` when passing `String.class` as the second parameter.

Comment: Java 11, it's a compilation error received from IntelliJ. 
I'm pretty certain I haven't missed anything, but will recheck to verify...
The Object return-type is when I remove the wildcard everywhere and the method looks as follows:
```
    public void handleData(FieldDataProvider fieldDataProvider){...}
```

Comment: It compiles just fine for me even with Java 8. Maybe try a `Build -> Rebuild Project` or `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202352/discussion-between-jacob-g-and-wouter).